# how to expand and collapse the UItable view cell on button click

Tags: uitableview

Has anyone seen a script like this or would be willing to help out with one?

---

### Collapse/Expand Button

The uitableview cell to be expanded partially open (giving a preview in essence)

---

After the button is pressed then the cell of table would expand to show the entire contents (with a nice fade effect). If you chose to collapse the cell then it would return to the original offset (preview) height.

Has anyone seen anything like this? I've found a plethora of these scripts that fully expand or collapse, but not like this

Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to make custom cell class. While creating cell give the height of the cell as maximum you want (i.e when it expands) and when creating the custom cell drag a UIView and put all the contents in this view and hides this view. Then when button is being Tapped just you have to make it unhidden.